# Why function looks different when I plot it in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why those plotted functions look different?
I plotted function from Khan Academy video in Wolfram Alpha and it looks different... I cannot understand why
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wolfram just plotted you the two function separatly and not as a parametric curve of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Try

> **ParametricPlot[{t Cos[t], t Sin[t]},{t,$0$, $2$ Pi}]**

Comment: many thanks! I just started with W.A. so I did not know how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

These are two totally different kinds of plots.  The first is plotting all points of the form $(t\cos t,t\sin t)$ where $t$ can be any real number (this is called a *parametric* plot, with $t$ as the "parameter").

The second is instead plotting the functions $t\mapsto t\cos t$ and $t\mapsto t\sin t$ separately.  In other words, it is plotting the points $(t,t\sin t)$ and $(t,t\cos t)$ for all $t$.